# SSRS report accessable to clients

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm new in SSRS, my question is how do i make my reports accessible to client?
and can i change the url from:"http://serverName/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReports%" to
"http://company.co.za/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReports%" 
? do i need to authenticate users in Site Settings?

Answer (score 0):

The Report Manager portal is not especially designed to make reports accessible to the outside world. You can do it, but it needs careful planning and consideration. Here's your starting point:

[Planning For Extranet or Internet Deployment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159272(v=sql.105).aspx)

Note that the link suggests you create a custom web application and embed the Report Viewer control: this will allow you to present the user interface of your choice to the users and help you deal with security. However the Report Manager portal you ask about is also an option.

Comment: so cant if i change sql authentication and add a new user account specifically for this and give limited rights will it work?@Rich

Comment: Is your server on the internet? Of course, it will need to be- but assuming that's true, the article still gives lots of concerns you'll need to address. Giving someone user rights is probably small fry compared to what you need to do- I'd recommend following the article through and make sure you have covered or are able to cover all the main points.